# Sitecore 10.3 error after security bulletin installation- Could not find property 'alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder'

Tags: sitecore-api

Recently I installed security bulletin https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002844 for Sitecore 10.3.

After that I am getting below error in my docker instance.

```
Could not find property 'alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder' on object of type: Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find property 'alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder' on object of type: Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Could not find property 'alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder' on object of type: Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +2356
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +161
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +114
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config) +105
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(List`1 nodes) +596
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider) +323
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders() +75
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider() +116
   Sitecore.Links.DefaultLinkManager.ParseRequestUrl(HttpRequest request) +42
   Sitecore.Web.RequestUrl.Parse(HttpRequestBase request) +123
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs.Initialize() +31
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +118
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnBeginRequest(HttpContextBase context) +172
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.HttpApplication_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +223
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +232
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +100
```

Though I doubt that security bulletin caused this error but I am not sure.
Does anybody else have this issue? Any idea about this error?

Comment: https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2023/08/sitecore-1031-config-file-includes.html

Comment: That's of great help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all really well explained in the article here:

https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2023/08/sitecore-1031-config-file-includes.html

In shortcut:

- Sitecore 10.3.1 `Sitecore.config` has a new `alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder` setting for `urlBuilder`. It's same with the hotfix.
- This doesn't well with 10.3.0 libraries - make sure that if you reference right version of libraries (either from 10.3.1 or from the hotfix), you don't override then again with 10.3.0 libraries while publishing the project.
- Ideally, upgrade the whole project to 10.3.1 and use 10.3.1 nuget libraries.